# Unprocessable Content in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an error with my update data form, I use laravel as backend and frontend API, on the create data form there is no problem, but on the update data form I get this error (PUT http://localhost:8000/api/employees/1 422 (Unprocessable Content)), is there anyone who can help me I'm stuck on this issue.

My form

```
<div class="card">
    <form action="/employees/{{ $id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-id="{{ $id }}"
        id="editEmployee">
        <div class="card-body">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $name }}">
                <span id="handleErrorName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" value="{{ $phone }}">
                <span id="handleErrorPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" value="{{ $address }}">
                <span id="handleErrorAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Status</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status">
                    <option value="active" {{ $status == 'active' ? 'selected' : '' }}>active</option>
                    <option value="inactive" {{ $status == 'inactive' ? 'selected' : '' }}>inactive</option>
                </select>
                <span id="handleErrorStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Photo</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
                <span id="handleErrorImage" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("editEmployee").addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const id = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('image');
        let file = null;
        if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
            file = fileInput.files[0];
        }

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value);
        formData.append('phone', document.getElementById('phone').value);
        formData.append('address', document.getElementById('address').value);
        formData.append('status', document.getElementById('status').value);
        formData.append('image', file);

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/employees/${id}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: formData
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const errors = await response.json();

                for (const field in errors) {
                    const errorMessage = errors[field][0];
                    const errorElement = document.getElementById(
                        'handleError');
                    if (errorElement) {
                        errorElement.textContent = errorMessage;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert('Employee data updated successfully!');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error: ', error);
        }

    });
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $employees = Employee::find($id);

    if (!$employees) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee data not found!'], 404);
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'image'   => 'nullable|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048',
        'name'    => 'required',
        'phone'   => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'status'  => 'required',
    ], [
        'image.mimes'       => 'The file format does not match. The file must be JPG or PNG.',
        'image.max'         => 'The file size is too large. The maximum file size is 2MB (2048KB).',
        'name.required'     => 'The name field is required.',
        'phone.required'    => 'The phone field is required.',
        'address.required'  => 'The address field is required.',
        'status.required'   => 'The status field is required.',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors()->toArray(), 422);
    }

    $data = $request->all();

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $filename = Storage::disk('uploads')->put('image', $request->image);
        $data['image'] = $filename;
        if (@$employees->image) {
            File::delete('./uploads/image/' . basename($employees->image));
        }
    }

    $employees->update($data);

    return new EmployeeResource(true, 'Employee data successfully updated!', $employees);
}
```

I have filled out all the forms but still display a response like this

```json
{
    "name": [
        "The name field is required."
    ],
    "phone": [
        "The phone field is required."
    ],
    "address": [
        "The address field is required."
    ],
    "status": [
        "The status field is required."
    ] }
```

I've searched for the same error from Stack overflow but I still can't find a solution

Comment: When you dd($request->all()) in your controller what do you get? If its empty then console log the form data since it may be not passing the data.

Comment: Can you try and copy and paste the cURL generated from your network tab for the POST request?

Comment: You cannot transfer binary data (in your case the image) via PUT, use POST instead for this.